# How to validate SQL scripts without executing in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I was trying to validate all my SQL files using the below scripts but somehow its throwing an error. Need help.

```
cd D:\My_System\rgbumerch\test

Get-ChildItem .\*.sql | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | ForEach { $query = (Get-Content -Path $_); Check-Query-Syntax $str }
```

Error:

> Check-Query-Syntax : The term 'Check-Query-Syntax' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
> included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:2 char:102
> + ...  ForEach { $query = (Get-Content -Path $_); Check-Query-Syntax $str }
> +                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Check-Query-Syntax:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: What is Check-Query-Syntax supposed to be?

Comment: .. and `$str` is also undefined..

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `Check-Query-Syntax $str` for this `Check-Query-Syntax $query`

Comment: Also, can you please share how the function `Check-Quey-Syntax` is declared or how you import the module?